# PyYAML: official example failed

Tags: python, pyyaml

I am trying to run an official example in [the PyYAML documentation](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#constructors-representers-resolvers). However, it failed with the following error:

```
yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here
  in "<unicode string>",
```

Below is my code. `m` is running successfully, and `n` raises error. The difference between `m` and `n` is the absence of "`---`".

```
import yaml

class Monster(yaml.YAMLObject):
    yaml_tag = '!Monster'
    def __init__(self, name, hp, ac, attacks):
        self.name = name
        self.hp = hp
        self.ac = ac
        self.attacks = attacks
    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s(name=%r, hp=%r, ac=%r, attacks=%r)" % (
            self.__class__.__name__, self.name, self.hp, self.ac,      
            self.attacks)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    m = yaml.load("""
    !Monster
    name: Cave spider
    hp: [2,6]    # 2d6
    ac: 16
    attacks: [BITE, HURT]
    """)
    print(m)


    n = yaml.load("""
    --- !Monster
    name: Cave spider
    hp: [2,6]    # 2d6
    ac: 16
    attacks: [BITE, HURT]
    """)
    print(n)
```

1. Why?
2. If I want to load from string to init several instances, could you please show me the code?

Comment: It seems that the problem with your `n` is that it is indented incorrectly. Indentations in triple quoted strings go into the string, so to replicate the official example, you should not indent them.

Comment: @ImperishableNight Thank u, I remove the indent,then the n runs successfully

Answer (score 0):

In the "n" version, you are trying to load a YAML file that starts with the multi-line non-quoted scalar
`--- !Monster name`, such a scalar is not allowed to be a mapping key. If you want to do that you need to quote the scalar with double or single quotes (I added the YAML comment to make the indentation more clear):

```
# n-example    
    "--- !Monster
    name": Cave spider
    hp: [2,6]    # 2d6
    ac: 16
    attacks: [BITE, HURT]
```

or put the non-quoted mapping key on one line

```
# n-example    
    --- !Monster name: Cave spider
    hp: [2,6]    # 2d6
    ac: 16
    attacks: [BITE, HURT]
```

In the example from the documentation, the `---` is not indented and then it is a [document start marker](https://yaml.org/spec/1.1/#id897596), which also changes the meaning of the `!` grom a normal mid-scalar exclamation mark to the start of a tag. The best way to solve this, and keep your code nicely indented and readable is by using `dedent`:

```
from textwrap import dedent:

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = yaml.load(dedent("""\
    --- !Monster
    name: Cave spider
    hp: [2,6]    # 2d6
    ac: 16
    attacks: [BITE, HURT]
    """))
print(n)
```

In the newer YAML 1.2 specification (released 2009, not supported by PyYAML), `---` was renamed [directives end marker](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2800401) and functions subtly different.

Comment: Thank u for ur share.